# What is the shortcut to find next occurrence of a word in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts

In Eclipse the keyboard shortcut to find next occurrence of a word in a file was `Ctrl + k` . It finds the occurrence of the selected word in a file one by one in a loop. What is the equivalent keyboard shortcut for IntelliJ IDEA? If not can we configure it some how?

Comment: On linux: Ctrl-L (Ctrl-Shift-L for the previous occurrence)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

First you'll have to highlight a symbol by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>.

Then you just press <kbd>F3</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> no navigate between the highlighted symbols.

When done you press Esc to exit the highlight searching.

It is all described on [Highlightning Usages](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/highlighting-usages.html) in [IntelliJ Web Help](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/getting-help.html).

Comment: Wait a pain. And it doesn't work well. Press Ctrl+Shift+F7 twice by accident and it's all screwed up. It's so simple in Eclipse...

Comment: When I search using Ctrl + Shift + F (global search), the F3 does not find the next occurrence.

Answer (score 26):

Add selection for the next occurrence on Linux `Alt+J`

Comment: Unfortunately 1) you need to press Esc at the end of the search to switch to the single cursor from multiple ones and 2) immediately after that your cursor moves back to the point from which you started the search (while usually you want it at the point where the search has just finished)

Answer (score 21):

Finding [Next Occurrence of the Word at Caret](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/navigating-through-the-source-code.html#find_cursor_edit): <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd>.

Comment: I remapped this to `Ctrl+3` since `Ctrl+F3` is a window manager shortcut (switch to 3rd virtual desktop).

Comment: This is simple and better solution than the accepted one!

Comment: It only searches to the end of the file (doesn't perform circle search in a file). To continue search from the beginning of a file you need to switch to `F3` which is awkward.

Answer (score 17):

On Mac it's `Command + G`, but you can check what works for your OS by looking at `Edit -> Find -> Find Next...`.

[image]

AFAIK you have to select the word in the search bar first.. So, `Command + F` and then `Command + G` to go to the next occurrence.

Answer (score 15):

In Android Studio 1.4, apparently Mac OS default keyboard shortcuts for ***element next occurrence*** (vars, methods, etc) are

- NEXT/FWD: <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>
- PREVIOUS: <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>

*I did try all the answers w/out success, and finally I looked it up in Prefs->Key Bindings*

Comment: Applies to PyCharm on Mac too.

Answer (score 7):

There are also hotkeys for navigating next/previous highlighted usages.

Several years ago they were <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Wheel down</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Wheel up</kbd>. Today they are not set by default.

You can find them in `Keymap` preferences with `highlighted element usage` search phrase.

[image: Keymap Preferences search highlighted element usage]

Answer (score 7):

Please consider using the [Multiple Selections](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2014/03/intellij-idea-13-1-rc-introduces-sublime-text-style-multiple-selections/) for this:

1. Select the term you want to lookup;
2. Use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> / <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> / <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> for Mac OS X) to select other occurrences.

It will work the same as <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd>, but it will select every next occurrences. I found this way much more conveniant, as you can choose to edit all the matching string or just move the cursor to edit the last selected one (<kbd>←/→</kbd>).

The [Multiple Selections](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2014/03/intellij-idea-13-1-rc-introduces-sublime-text-style-multiple-selections/) feature is available since  IntelliJ IDEA 13.1 RC, and compete with [Atom](https://atom.io) or [Sublime Text](https://www.sublimetext.com) similar feature.

Answer (score 2):

I could not get any of IntelliJ's native options for Find Next/Previous to behave like in Eclipse. `Find Word at Caret` comes close, but it only allows you to slurp and find the next word, not previous.

I wrote an IntelliJ plugin to reproduce the exact behavior as in Eclipse. You can find it here: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/10635-quick-find-plugin

Comment: I could find no way to simulate this Eclipse behavior in Intellij with the Keymaps.
But with you plugin it works like a charm and exactly as intended. Thanks for sharing this!

Answer (score 2):

you can set shortcuts same as in eclipse by setting keymap value as eclipse.

Steps in intellij:
Go to setting in file

search for keymap

[image: search for keymap]

In the dropdown section set Eclipse

Now all your shortcuts are same as in eclipse.

Comment: This definitely does not do the trick. It's of course the first thing I have tried though.
Setting the Keymap to the Eclipse profile will only change some mappings to be similar to Eclipse.
If you have to switch from Eclipse to Intellij, then you will constantly have to fix the Keymappings - one by one...

Answer (score 2):

For MAC:
First you'll have to highlight a symbol by pressing `Command+Shift+F7.`

Then for next occurrence `Command+G` or `Command+Shift+G`

Answer (score 1):

For those who use [IdeaVim](https://github.com/JetBrains/ideavim) plugin, there is another option.

Add these entries into `.ideavimrc`:

```
map <C-j> <Action>(GotoNextElementUnderCaretUsage)
map <C-k> <Action>(GotoPrevElementUnderCaretUsage)
```

This maps the navigation to the next/previous element under caret using ctrl+j/ctrl+k. Of course you can map it to something else, but this suggestion follows the standard navigation keys in vim.

Answer (score 0):

[IntelliJ Keyboard Shortcuts](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Reference__Keyboard_Shortcuts.html)

On Ubuntu:

Next occurrence of selected word: F3

Comment: Yeah this works but surprisingly it is taking the last word searched and not the current highlighted word to search for the next occurrence.

Comment: If you highlight the word then you'll need to press ctrl-f and then enter. Sorry, 2 keypresses, unless u make a macro or the like...

Answer (score 0):

On my Mac it is:

```
ctrl-l to find next occurrence
ctrl-shift-l to find previous occurrence
```

Comment: This doesn't work on Mac OS X El Capitan (10.11.5):  But the Answer by @gnB does!

Answer (score 0):

To expand the question slightly, the method to display the next occurrence of a search term in the *Find In Path* pane, is to steer to it using the up/down arrows and then hit *Enter*.

Answer (score 0):

Start by looking for all occurrence of the key (control + g)

Then use ( shift + command + g ) to find previous occurrence and ( command + g ) to find next occurrence.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution to navigate through occurrences in IntellijIdea.

Press `ctrl+shift+f` → `Open in Find Window`.
Then you can navigate through occurrences with `ctrl+alt+↓` or `ctrl+alt+↑`.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).