# How to go to next/previous occurrence in current editor tab?

Tags: intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts

In eclipse, you can go to the previous/next occurrence of the selected word by pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd> / <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd>.

What is the equivalent in IntelliJ IDEA?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the shortcut to find next occurrence of a word in IntelliJ IDEA?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17585273/what-is-the-shortcut-to-find-next-occurrence-of-a-word-in-intellij-idea)

Comment: On linux: Ctrl-L (Ctrl-Shift-L for the previous occurrence)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The functions for this are called `Go to {next,previous} highlighted element usage` and are available by default only via the menu `Edit`→`Find`.  No key press is associated to this function by default.  (IntelliJ IDEA 2018.3 (Community Edition))

You can set them to a specific key press in the keymap: `File`→`Settings`→`Keymap`→`Main menu`→`Edit`→`Find` and double click on the function you want to set.

**EDIT**:
IntelliJ IDEA 2021.3 (Community Edition): via main menu `Edit`→`Find Usage`→`Next(Previous) Highlighted Usage`

Comment: Now it has a default shortcut(on mac): ctrl + alt + ↓, which is just like ctrl + k in Eclipse.

Comment: Next "Highlighted" usage is a bit different from next "Occurrence" - will jump right to the next location without having to establish a find/search for the pattern. Not sure of the equivalent behavior in eclipse, but much more useful IMO than "occurrence" in IJ, and definitely worth adding a shortcut for next/prev "Highlighted Usage" if not already setup on your IJ.

Answer (score 33):

The feature is called [Find Word at Caret](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/finding-word-at-caret.html):

> Search for a word at caret enables you to quickly find the exact match for the current word, without changing any search options. With the match once found, you can navigate between the occurrences of the term.

You can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> for that:

- select a word at caret
- hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> and then <kbd>F3</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> to   navigate to the
  next/previous occurrence

#### Mac OS

Please note that there is no shortcut on Mac OS. You'd need to use <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> and type "Find Word At Caret" ("find wo" should be enough) or on the main menu, choose **Edit | Find | Find Word At Caret**. Press <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>g</kbd> to navigate to go to the next occurrence.

#### Separate Plugin

Or, try [this plugin](http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/?idea&id=6318) - it supports using  <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd> to navigate up and down to each identifier occurrence

To make this feature available by default please, vote for [IDEA-59638](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-59638)

Answer (score 11):

Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> to highlight the usages of some variable in the current file, then use <kbd>F3</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> to navigate through the highlighted usages.

(It works in IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1.3)

Comment: IntelliJ style.....Press ctrl + shift + alt + f7 + c +o (twice) + put your nose on space + sing a little song....to perform a useful function that Eclipse has on ctrl + . ¯\(º o)/¯

Comment: Close editor tab: Ctrl + F4.............Closed my IntelliJ window by accidently hitting Alt + F4 471 times just today.......ᕙ(⇀‸↼‶)ᕗ

Answer (score 5):

[Finding Word at Caret](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/finding-word-at-caret.html): <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd>:

> Search for a word at caret enables you to quickly find the exact match for the current word, without changing any search options. With the match once found, you can navigate between the occurrences of the term.

Note that after it has found occurrences, it immediately goes to the first occurrence.

Answer (score 2):

```
CMD + Shift + F7 to select all occurrences
than CMD + G to navigate forward
CMD + Shift + G to navigate backward
```